# .NET API for HID (USB)?

Tags: c#, .net, api, usb, hid

Is there an API in .NET (C#) for using USB HID (human interface) devices?

Comment: Duplate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749/working-with-usb-devices-in-net

Comment: Not totally a duplicate -- this question deals with HID (which I'm assuming means "driverless" HID), so the answers to the other question don't all apply to this one.

Comment: No - HID actually means all existing or yet not invented devices that humans may interact with or not interact soo much. Let it be a temp sensor or a button or a colorimeter. Some data in, some out (low amounts)

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net . It supports .Net Core, Framework, Android, and UWP.

Answer (score 11):

[HidLibrary](http://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary) wraps up all the [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) calls for you. But no, it doesn't look there are any nice framework APIs for dealing with USB devices.

Comment: +1 for HidLibrary; I was starting to go down the road of rolling my own C# wrapper lib for the kernal32 and hid.dlls.  HidLibrary has already done the hard work (mostly) and provides a clean, simple API at that.  Got me up and running amazingly fast (like, minutes).  And you can install it with nuget, which is nice.  There are other c# hid.dll wrapper libs out there, but nothing quite so clean that I've seen.

Comment: That library is no longer supported.

Comment: HidLibrary is Windows only. Device.Net supports Hid and USB on Android, Windows, and UWP. https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://github.com/MightyDevices/MightyHID) mine little library for dealing with HID devices.

It might be useful, especially when you are trying to communicate using raw HID reports. I've also [included a simple demonstration](https://github.com/MightyDevices/MightyHID/tree/master/MightyHIDTest) of how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing direct or high-level. There are some things you can do through the managed [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) API, but I've personally found a lot of WMI interaction with hardware to be cryptic at best and requiring a lot of trial-and-error to get it to do what you want.

Someone on [The Code Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Project) has developed a .NET [component for USB HID](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USB_HID.aspx) you can try out that's probably going to fit the bill better than WMI.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you follow [this example](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/) instead. It was invaluable in getting me up and running with HiD dev in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start here: http://wiimotelib.codeplex.com/

Comment: Why? A Nintendo Wiimote library!?

Comment: Because the Wiimote is a HID device under windows, and that codeplex project has all the p/Invoke work needed to communicate with a HID device from the CLR done for you in the HDImports class

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library on Google Code:

*[C# USB HID driver](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-usb-hid-driver/)*

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this: [Simple HID Library](http://simplehidlibrary.codeplex.com/). The main page has a list of other open source libraries.

Comment: It is very unstable, especially on Win7

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for it. I'm using the code I found here:
http://janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm