# How to use visual basic to read data byte-by-byte via serial communication?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, serial-port, microcontroller, serial-communication

I am trying to read out some serial data from my STM32 board to GUI, and also, I have trouble closing down my serial communication port.

I am using 2013 Visual Studio and chose Visual Basic as my programming language. What I wanted to send from the microcontroller is some serial data that I sent byte-by-byte. So, for example, I will be sending `"<abcde>"` from my microcontroller with `"<"` and `">"` as my start and stop bit; and hopefully my visual basic GUI will read and display it.

I have tried to display it at visual basic using serialport.readexisting() with no problem, but then I need to separate each bytes by itself. In the end, I wanted my program to read and process each byte, which will be some sensor values and can display it in the VB program.

I have tried using both serialport.read() and serialport.readbyte() but I don't know why, it does not show the correct output. What I meant of not correct is that the ascii code nor characters does not represent on what I sent from the microcontroller.

Here is the time when I use readbyte().

```
'Visual Basic --> for serialport.readbyte()
Dim buff_rx As Byte
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived_1(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    SerialPort1.ReadTimeout = 20
    Do While SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0
        Try
            buff_rx = SerialPort1.ReadByte
            Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf update_dat))

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Loop
End Sub

Public Sub update_dat(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim i As Integer = buff_rx
    Dim s As String = ""
    s = i.ToString("X2") 'if wanted to be in hex, use "X2"
    Rx_text.Text = Rx_text.Text & " " & i
End Sub
```

Here is the part when I tried using the read() part.

```
'Visual Basic --> for serialport1.read()

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived_1(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim bytestoread As Int16
    bytestoread = SerialPort1.BytesToRead
    Dim buff(bytestoread) As Byte
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.Read(buff, 0, bytestoread - 1))
End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.Rx_text.InvokeRequired Then 'form 1 is Me'
        Dim k As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(k, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.Rx_text.Text &= [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

This part below is when I send the data from microcontroller

```
//Microcontroller side, data sending
tx3_buff[0] = '<'; //ascii code: 60
tx3_buff[1] = 'b'; //ascii code: 98
tx3_buff[2] = 'c'; //ascii code: 99
tx3_buff[3] = 'd'; //ascii code: 100
tx3_buff[4] = 'e'; //ascii code: 101
tx3_buff[5] = 'f'; //ascii code: 102
tx3_buff[6] = 'g'; //ascii code: 103
tx3_buff[7] = 'h'; //ascii code: 104
tx3_buff[8] = 'i'; //ascii code: 105
tx3_buff[9] = '>'; //ascii code: 62
```

The data that I was intended to send from the microcrontroller are shown on the code as well. As I mentioned before, when I used the serialport.readexisting(), I can correctly read "". But when I use either serialport.readbyte() and serialport.read() it reads:

```
160  16 161 33 198 18 52 68 84 200 232 16 40 200
```

and so on and so on which is definitely incorrect and made nonsense.

In terms of the close() problem, I put the serialport.close() inside the button function. I already tried from some forums that stated we should use begininvoke instead of only using invoke (like here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/)

But it still won't work.
Here is the Close button part:

```
'Visual Basic --> for disconnect button
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    SerialPort1.Close()
End Sub
```

Everytime after I pressed this button, it will always be stuck and hanged. I need to restart the program so this problem will be solved. Any ideas for this part?

To easily summarize, here are my problems:

1. I have literally no idea how to use the serialport.readbyte() and serialport.read(). I really need this as I wanted to separate the data byte-by-byte so I can process it easily.
2. The serialport.close() button always hangs and I don't know why.

I hope someone can help me with these problems. Thank you in advance for all your help and sorry if my thread is messy!

Thank you again!

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749/working-with-usb-devices-in-net

Comment: I don't know how you are sending the bytes, but be aware that in .NET (VB and C#), characters are 2 bytes long.

Comment: How is buff_rx declared? Why do you set i which is an integer = buff_rx which is a byte?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli Buff_Rx is a byte array, ah.. so is that the source of the problem? i thought that we can immediately store from the byte to integer?

Comment: @RobertBaron Hi, yes I have checked it, but unfortunately it doesn't answer my problem..

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Hi, thank you for making the thread much more neat! :) Ah okay, but what I did was sending from the microcontroller, which is sending data per 8 bits, to visual basic. Will this impose problem as well, as you mentioned one character are 2 bytes long?

Comment: Yes, see [Char Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/char-data-type). But it does not explain the values you are receiving.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli Thank you for pointing out the data type! I can finally read the correct data here at the display finally!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thank you for the link! I will try to learn it.. :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buff_Rx is a byte array and can't be assigned to an integer:

```
Dim i As Integer = buff_rx
```